# Visual Studio 2017 nenhum template

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Instalado o VS2017 porém não aparece os templates apenas 'Blank Solution'.
Tentei desinstalar e reinstalar sem sucesso.
Alguém já passou por essa situação?

Imagem:
[image: Template]

[image: Install]

Comment: Escolheste algum tipo de projecto no instalador?

Comment: Sim Escolhi '.NET desktop development', entre outros. porém não apareceu nenhum template.

Comment: Após diversos testes, consegui fazer aparecer Instalei o VS2015 e copiei a pasta _'ProjectTemplates'_ e colei no VS2017, porém não me parece correto, como se estivesse faltando alguma coisa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obrigado pelas respostas. Ajudaram bastante como paliativo porém não solucionaram definitivamente.
Após eu abrir um bug na microsoft eles não conseguiram resolver, porém depois atualizei para a ultima versão liberada recentemente ele voltou a funcionar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa instalar pelo instalador do Visual Studio.
[image: Instalador VS]

Clique na aba "Workload" no canto superior esquerdo, então marque no canto direito ".NET-Desktop Development" e clique em instalar. Note que isso pode modificar o tamanho de sua instalação (Canto inferior direito), e você pode instalar outros Workloads, mas você deve instalar pelo menos o ".NET-Desktop Development".

[image: Workloads]

Se feito isso você ainda não conseguir ver os templates, então o Visual Studio provavelmente está pegando os templates dos seus "Custom Templates" e não instalados. Para resolver isso, copie a pasta dos templates instalados
para os custom.

Pasta de instalados: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates"

Pasta dos custom: "C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Templates\ProjectTemplates"

Fonte: [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41189398/no-templates-in-visual-studio-2017)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Porém infelizmente já fiz isso esta marcado o ".NET-Desktop Development"., já desinstalei e reinstalei instalando apenas ele e continua igual.

Comment: Copiando o ProjectTemplates funciona. Porém não sei se seria o correto, visto que instalei outras opções no 'worload' e não está aparecendo..

Comment: Alguma ideia?.. pois a pasta que mencionou em cima é da do vs2015, embora funcione, o vs2017 deveria instalar corretamente.

Comment: Apesar da versão, a pasta é a do VS17 mesmo. Mas infelizmente é difícil apontar a causa exata do porque o VS não instala corretamente, seria necessários vários testes em vários ambientes pra tentar chegar numa resposta, e ainda sim, ela pode não ser unica. A questão é que se alguns dos procedimentos citados solucionou o problema, já é alguma resposta válida e que pode ser útil pra alguém.

Comment: Perfeito. Apenas para finalizar.. quando adiciona uma nova classe Shift + Alt + C,  tbm não aparece a classe. Saberia  como acertar?